# How do I play Trackmania Nations Forever via Hamachi?

Tags: hamachi, trackmania-forever

How to play Trackmania Nations via Hamachi?

What do I have to click?

**Update**: The hamachi network is established, but the participants do not see any local created server.

Comment: [Related.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6924/how-to-play-borderlands-via-hamachi) [Also related.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30/what-should-we-do-about-excessive-content-seeding)

Comment: Just to make sure... You meant Trackmania Nations Forever, right?

Answer (score 2):

I have had **much** better luck with [Tunngle](http://www.tunngle.net/en/) than Hamachi for games.  Try it out!

If there is no channel for your game, just join another channel; it usually works.

---

The only bit of setup I've ever had to do with Tunngle *(which I also had to do with Hamachi, along with many, many other things)* is that some games *(ex. Age of 
Mythology)* will view your internet connection as your primary adapter, even though Tunngle sets itself up as your primary adapter in Windows.  To work around this, you 
have to:

1. Start up Tunngle
2. Disable your primary internet adapter in the *Network Connections* settings
3. Start up the game
4. Reenable your primary internet connection

Answer (score 1):

Check [THIS](http://elektroniikka.org/hamachi/) step-by-step Hamachi installation & configuration guide, it comes with screenshots and detailed explanation. Should the link rot, here's what you want to do:

1. Do *not* launch Hamachi after having [downloaded](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx) and installed it.
2. When you are asked, set the Hamachi network as a *Home network*.
3. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and search the settings for "Network connections," press Enter.
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> then pick *Advanced* → *Advanced settings* → *Adapters and Bindings* tab.
5. Bring the Hamachi network to the top and confirm with *Ok*.
6. Right click on the Hamachi network and pick *Properties.*
7. Uncheck "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)".
8. Select "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" and pick *Properties*.
9. From the *General* tab press *Advanced* and disable the *Automatic metric* feature. Use `1` instead.
10. Now launch Hamachi, power it on, register and pick *Manage* → *Manage connections*
11. Pick *Manage Hamachi for free* and then login with your account (register if needed.)
12. Go *Networks* → *My Networks* on the navigation bar; click on *Create Networks.*
13. Name your network and make it a *Mesh* network. Press *Continue*.
14. Configure the network as you like. Select the Free Subscription and *Continue*.
15. Take the network ID from the network list.
16. Use it in the *Join network* button on the Hamachi interface.
17. If you weren't asked yet, set the Hamachi network as a home network.
18. If necessary whitelist Hamachi from your firewall.
19. If necessary do port forwarding on ports TCP 12975, TCP 32976 and UDP 17771.

Comment: Please don't just link to an off-site guide, no matter how comprehensive it may be

Answer (score 0):

Just create/join an Hamachi Network. You should be able to create and join games via the *Party Play* → *Over a local network* screen.

[Related video on Youtube.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8OOZfuRSNM)

Comment: yah, the gameserver does not appear in the list of available lan-games