# How do I play Borderlands via Hamachi?

Tags: borderlands, hamachi

How to play Borderlands via Hamachi?

What do I have to click?

Comment: Have you tried [this?](http://www.cybergamer.com.au/forums/thread/36776/How-to-play-Borderlands-on-Hamachi/)

Comment: Have you tried [Tunngle](http://www.tunngle.net/en/)?  I've had much more recent success with it than Hamachi

Answer (score 2):

There is a good guide about PC connections in Borderlands [here](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Connection_Issues). It contains also a step by step guide to use Hamachi.